How to use settings section Variables Python.py in robot framework
In robot framework my sample.resource file looks like this
*** Settings ***

Library           OperatingSystem
Variables         da_cfg.py

The da_cfg.py file return a dictionary imported from yaml file
But how can that dictionary returned used inside the resource file to access the value for a particular key
Example
Test Connection
    [Arguments]    ${args}
    Set Test Variable  @{cfg}  Get From Dictionary  ${args}
    Log  ${cfg}

I tried to use
*** Keywords ***

Test Connection
    [Arguments]    ${args}
    Set Test Variable  ${cfg} ${${args}}
    Log  ${cfg}

I am able to get entire value for key args using ${${args}} sytax but not using Get From Dictionary.
${${args}} using makes code not readable. I want to fetch the value using inbuilt library in RF

What is the name of the dictionary defined in Variables?

This is the code inside python file which will load a yaml file which has stored in dictionary like data
import os
import yaml
def get_variables(arg1="", arg2='d_cfg.yaml'):
cfg_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file)), arg2)
with open(cfg_path, 'r') as f:
remote_cfg = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
if arg1 == "":
return remote_cfg
return remote_cfg[arg1]
Yaml file look like :
Dict1:
server_name: 'server1'
server_type: 'datastore'

That is too complicated for a Variable file definitions. Can't you use the yaml file directly? Robot supports variable files in YAML and also in JSON. Other option is to make that python code as imported library. Note, I don0t know if the variables definition is working. you can use the keyword Log Variables to see how they are actually defined.

It is already existing code, I cannot modify the structure ,
If I use ${${args}} the dictionary key is expanded and all the values under it is available in the resource file. How did that happened , is the entire contents of the yaml file is also imported inside resource file as a hidden data.
But when I tried like this  @{cfg}=    Get Dictionary Items  ${args} it is showing an TypeError: Expected argument 1 to be a dictionary, got string instead.
I am not able to understand the magic behind this ${${args}}

What I can suggest, is for you to create a minimal sample that you can share with us. Create a YAML with proper format and simple content like: Dict1: server_name: 'server1' server_type: 'datastore' . Then try to make a python code to process it. Or try to use it directly in test suite. You must test if you can get the server_type key, for example.

Able to achieve it using this way
${variable} =    Get Variables    no_decoration=Yes.
This has returned the entire scope variables used in the suite to $variable, from there I was able to get the dictionary contents I needed.
${cfg} =  Get From Dictionary  ${variable}    Dict1

Maybe you can write your comment as the answer for your question.

Able to achieve it using:
${variable} = Get Variables no_decoration=Yes.

This returns the entire scope variables used in the suite to $variable. From there, you can get the dictionary contents needed:
${cfg} = Get From Dictionary ${variable} Dict1

